# Chrome URL prediction not working as expected

Tags: google-chrome

I've been using URL prediction a lot, and suddenly yesterday it stopped behaving like it did before. I tried to reset settings to default but that didn't work.

For example, before if I wrote a `g` in the url bar, it automatically predicted to `gmail.com` (which is the one site beginning with `g` that I visit the most), and now, it uses other predictions like `google.com`, etc., including some searches I did before beginning with `g`.

Also, it's now completely reversed; first it shows me the searches I've done long ago, which I don't care about anymore, and then the URLs.

How I can make it show the URL first like it did before? Here is an example, the search comes first, but it shouldn't:

[image: Here is an example, the search come first, but it shouldn't]

I tried to resets settings to default but didn't work.

Thanks for your help.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Can I make Chrome omnibox autofill prioritize URLs before searches?](https://superuser.com/questions/1442690/can-i-make-chrome-omnibox-autofill-prioritize-urls-before-searches)