# Can I make Chrome omnibox autofill prioritize URLs before searches?

Tags: google-chrome, omnibox

I started encountering this issue after a recent Chrome update. Omnibox autocomplete now returns previous searches before previously visited URLs. This is annoying for me as I'm used to typing in one or two characters of my most frequently visited URLs and hitting enter to access them. Is it possible to return to this configuration?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm having this issue as well. This fixed it for me:

- Go to `chrome://flags/#omnibox-drive-suggestions`
- Set the flag "Omnibox Google Drive Document suggestions" to disabled

Source: https://techdows.com/2019/05/fix-chrome-autofills-recent-searches-instead-of-urls.html

It's unclear exactly why this works. It appears to be a bug:
https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=962599

Comment: Please post the relevant information from the linked page, as the link may become unavailable or the content may change.

Comment: Thanks! This was really annoying me. Luckily it's a bug so it'll be fixed at some point: https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=962599

Answer (score 0):

This is the flag you want to disable:

**`chrome://flags/#omnibox-group-suggestions-by-search-vs-url`** = `Disabled`

> Omnibox Group Suggestions By Search vs URL
>
> *Group suggestions by major type, search then navigation, except for
>   the default match which must be first. – Mac, Windows, Linux, Chrome
>   OS, Android*