# Chrome sometimes does not suggest base URL

Tags: google-chrome, address-bar, omnibox

This is not tied to a particular version of Chrome but has happened occasionally over the years. Sometimes the "base" address stops getting suggested in the autocomplete (or even the dropdown options) of the ominbox.

For example, if I currently start typing `redd` I get `https://www.reddit.com/r/GlobalOffensive/` suggested. The base URL `https://www.reddit.com/` is not even suggested in the dropdown. To not get the suggestion I have to type the full `reddit.com` or `reddit.com/`.

Why is it so and how to prevent that?

I must note that I have not intentionally deleted `https://www.reddit.com/` from my history or ShiftDeleted it from the suggestions. In fact I haven't intentionally cleared my history at all in quite some time. And I am not (was not, before this) visiting that `https://www.reddit.com/r/GlobalOffensive/` a lot, especially not through manual entry. If anything, I manually type `r/all` from time to time.

Note: I am aware I can "solve" it by deleting every competing entry, but I do want to keep those entries. It just feels like Chrome is getting prioritization wrong in some cases.

Comment: The loss of control feeling is similar to how one accidental `/` after your search term will forever complete `yoursearchterm` to `yoursearchterm/` and try to visit `http://yoursearchterm/`.

Comment: Seems to be a duplicate.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Can I make Chrome omnibox autofill prioritize URLs before searches?](https://superuser.com/questions/1442690/can-i-make-chrome-omnibox-autofill-prioritize-urls-before-searches)

Comment: @LayneBernardo I don't think so. This is not an issue of searches vs URLs, but just the wrong URL getting prioritized. Besides the bug in that question has been fixed already.

Comment: Hmm, not sure then. You can start with ^ to only check history, and * to only check bookmarks, but beyond that I'm not sure how you would fix this